# How to use pyinstaller to include images in the .exe

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am trying to make a simple pathfinding app with pygame and make it a .exe using pyinstaller.
Unfortunatly, the project uses images, and when I run the .exe, it comes back with telling me the images dont exist. How do I run pyinstaller to include the images?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the code ([mre])  that's loading the image as well as the error message and full traceback, if any, produced. There are also numerous similar question here, if you took the time to search for them…

Comment: Use this instead ::::

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you dont use the `--onefile` command, you can just drag and drop the images into the folder your exe is in. Or drop in the folder of images.

If you do use onefile, you need to modify the .spec file you get when you run the code `pyinstaller script.py`. Then run `pyinstaller scriptname.spec`. edit the `datas` variable somewhat like this

```
datas = [('src/image.png', '.'),
         ('src/image1.png' '.')]
```

If the images are in a different folder than your script you put the address of where they're at in regards to the script.

more information can be read in the [documentation](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html#using-spec-files)

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead -

##### If this is the pixmap then add the function below and call it in pixmap

```
self.label.setPixmap(
            QtGui.QPixmap(
                self.resource_path("MyPNG_FILE.png")
            )
        )
```

#### Add this function to your  code it will work for labels, images etc

```
### Use this function To attach files to the exe file (eg - png, txt, jpg etc) using pyinstaller
def resource_path(self, relative_path):
    """ Get absolute path to resource, works for dev and for PyInstaller """

    if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False) and hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS'):
        base_path = sys._MEIPASS
    else:
        base_path = os.path.abspath(".")

    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)
```